# Почему не выдаёт ответ из GET запроса?

Tags: javascript

Надо получить ответ

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только вместо

```
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
```

Я должен получить

```
<ans1>text1</ans1>
<ans2>text2</ans2>
```

Рабочий код (который выдаёт `<p>`):

```
var b = document.querySelector('div[style="top: 42px; width: 690px; padding: 0px 20px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; text-align: center; font: 32px/32px Arial;"]').textContent;
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open("GET", "https://100-k-1.ru/?s=" + encodeURIComponent(b), true);
a.onload = function (){
    var res = a.responseText
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(res, "text/html");
    var c = doc.querySelector(".entry").innerHTML;
    console.log(c);
}
a.send(null);
```

Не рабочий код (который должен выдовать `<ans>`):

```
var b = document.querySelector('div[style="top: 42px; width: 690px; padding: 0px 20px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; text-align: center; font: 32px/32px Arial;"]').textContent;
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open("GET", "https://100-k-1.ru/?s=" + encodeURIComponent(b), true);
a.onload = function (){
    var res = a.responseText
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(res, "text/html");
    var ans = [].forEach.call( doc.querySelectorAll('div p'),function(i,j){i.outerHTML = '<ans'+(j+1)+'>'+i.innerHTML+'</ans'+(j+1)+'>';});
    var c = ans.querySelector(".entry").innerHTML;
    console.log(c);
}
a.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не заменили `document.querySelectorAll` на  `doc.querySelectorAll`.

`forEach` ничего не возвращает:

```
/*var ans = */[].forEach.c...
var c = doc.querySelector(".entry").innerHTML;
```

```js
var res = `<div class="entry">
    <p>text1</p>
    <p>text2</p>
    </div>`;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(res, "text/html");
[].forEach.call(doc.querySelectorAll('div p'), function(i, j) {
  i.outerHTML = '<ans' + (j + 1) + '>' + i.innerHTML + '</ans' + (j + 1) + '>';
});
var c = doc.querySelector(".entry").innerHTML;
console.log(c);
```

Comment: выдаёт ошибку. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.a.onload

Comment: изменённый вариант выдаёт Uncaught ReferenceError: ans is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.a.onload